# Remove characters outside quotation mark python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to remove all characters outside quotation mark
for example this is my string

```
message = 'something "like" this'
print( removeFromQuote(message)  )


message2 = 'something "like this" thank you!'
print( removeFromQuote(message2)  )
```

**then the result :**

> like
>
> like this

how to create a function removeFromQuote that can do this.

or using re.sub with the correct regex

thank you in advance!

Comment: i already did but i cant find the right regex to implement ..

Comment: You accepted that answer? Why? No offense but that's not a good solution at all.

Comment: sorry,there answer is good and correct for me . but i preferred native way string manipulation with no import, thats the best although importing a lib still a good solution.

Comment: I see. No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, split the string on quotes.

```
message = 'something "like" this'
chunks = message.split('"')
```

The elements of the list that are bits of the text inside the quotes are the odd-numbered ones.  So just get those.

```
odd_chunks = chunks[1::2]
```

Now join the list back together into a string.

```
result = "".join(odd_chunks)
```

Putting it all together:

```
def removeFromQuote(text):
    return "".join(text.split('"')[1::2])
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `findall`:

```
import re
message = 'something "like this" thank you'
print(re.findall('"(\D+)"',message)[0])
```

Output:

```
like this
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re


def removeFromQuote(message):
    return re.findall(r'"(.+?)"', message)
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> message = 'something "like this" or "like that"'
>>> removeFromQuote(message)
['like this', 'like that']
```